# How to destructure an object by assigning default value when value is already null

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

The given object value can either of those.

```
const obj = null
const obj = { param : null}
const obj = { param : {innerParam: 10}}
```

I want to extract innerParam from param `const { param : {innerParam} ={}} =obj`
but it is throwing error Cannot destructure property 'innerParam' of ''{}'' as it is null. Is there a solution by assigning param to a default object while destructuring.

Note: I need a one liner code. I want avoid doing the below operation

```
const { param  = {} } =obj;
const { innerParam } = param || {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { innerParam } = (obj.param || {});
```

You still need to check that innerParam is defined. You can also add a default value like this:

```
const innerParam = ((obj.param || {}).innerParam) || "default";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { innerParam } = obj?.param
```

Comment: This is not valid vanilla JS.

Comment: actually this is valid

Comment: Yes, as ES6 it is. But not as JS5. Modern browser can use it but it is not going to work on legacy browsers. Also, this is a problematic syntax, as it is similar to the ternary operator ([cond] ? [if-true] : [if-false]) and can be misinterpreted by the interpreter. I wouldn't recommend this syntax.

Comment: Because of the ternary operator issue.

Comment: @xurei actually there is no ternary issue

Comment: Try with `const { innerParam } = obj?` ==> `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script`

Comment: @xurei  your point of 'this is a problematic syntax, as it is similar to the ternary operator ([cond] ? [if-true] : [if-false]) and can be misinterpreted by the interpreter.' this is no reasonable.optional chaining maybe confused by new jser, but not "interpreter". and there is no one will do `obj?` like this thing. this is ridiculous

Comment: `const { innerParam } = obj?` this is even not valid js statement. why would you want to try this way@xurei maybe you need read this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: That's my point! This syntax is confusing. It should be working, but it is not because of legacy features. Hence, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: BTW your link is invalid: there is a `</a` at the end

Comment: @xurei actually I think it depends. like other language for example C# or something already have Optional Chaining. so there is no reason don't use it in ESNext

Comment: Well let's agree to disagree I guess

Comment: it's up to you.